# git clone: warning: --depth is ignored in local clones; use file:// instead

Tags: git, git-clone, shallow-clone

We have a remote repository on a shared folder in our local network. I attempted to make a shallow clone:

```
git clone --depth 1 //gitrepos-pc/git/foo/
```

It gave me this warning, and made a full clone:

```
warning: --depth is ignored in local clones; use file:// instead.
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok, after some experimenting I got it, I had to use

```
git clone --depth 1 file:////gitrepos-pc/git/foo/
```

It had to be 4 slashes, not 3.

Edit:

Adding
@Dale's comment about relative paths:

> I found I couldn't use relative paths with file://, so I used $(pwd) to save myself a lot of typing: `git clone --depth 1 file://$(pwd)/src_repo new_repo`

Comment: `file://` is the protocol. `//` signifies a Samba share (from the Windows `\\`). Put those two together, and you've got `file:////`. It would be simpler if git understood the `smb://` protocol (it does, kind of, through `file://`, but I don't know it does this).

Comment: @rubenvb That explains it, thanks. So the usual 3 slashes is really `file://` + the starting slash of an ordinary local path I guess.

Comment: That's my guess to it yes `:)`.

Comment: How to use it with relative paths: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307578/how-to-shallow-clone-a-local-directory-in-git-with-a-relative-path

Comment: Note that when you specify a TARGET path to clone into (i.e. for outside of the current directory), you just use a standard local path for that argument.

Comment: In my case I had to use `file:///` instead to make it work.

Comment: I found I couldn't use relative paths with `file://`, so I used `$(pwd)` to save myself a lot of typing:   `git clone --depth 1 file://$(pwd)/src_repo new_repo`