# How to shallow clone a local git repository with a relative path?

Tags: git

Shallow clones of local directories require `file://` as explained at: [git clone: warning: --depth is ignored in local clones; use file:// instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383230/git-clone-warning-depth-is-ignored-in-local-clones-use-file-instead)

But how to use relative paths with that?

E.g.: if I have a repo `myrepo` in the current directory, and then I do:

```
git clone --depth 1 file://mymodule mymodule2
```

then it fails with:

```
Cloning into 'mymodule2'...
fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax
```

And if I try:

```
git clone --depth 1 file://./mymodule mymodule2
```

It fails with:

```
Cloning into 'mymodule2'...
fatal: '/./mymodule' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The only workaround I could find was to convert it to an absolute path starting with `/`:

```
git clone --depth 1 "file://$(pwd)/mymodule" mymodule2
```

Is there a profound reason for this behavior, or it just buggy?

Maybe file URIs simply don't support relative paths:

- [File Uri Scheme and Relative Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857416/file-uri-scheme-and-relative-files)
- https://superuser.com/questions/210263/file-to-point-a-relative-file-to-current-directory

git 2.14.1.

Comment: From the documentation for git clone: `git clone C:\folder1 folder2`  https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html#URLS

Comment: @IvanSheigets but isn't `C:\ ` an absolute path? And does it work with `--depth` without `file://`? In Linux `--depth` requires `file://`.

Comment: You are correct: URL/URI simply does not allow relative paths. Git probably should embrace-and-extend here, so as to allow it anyway.

Comment: This is killer. Thanks so much. Way too many people say this is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

It's neither necessary nor beneficial to shallow clone a local repo. Just `git clone ./relative/path` and you are good to go.

I assume you want to shallow copy because you want to save the disk space and save time, but

**1. It doesn't save disk space in local cloning.**

From Git 2.24.1 manual:

> For local repositories, also supported by Git natively, the following syntaxes may be
>          used:
>
> •   /path/to/repo.git/
>
> •   file:///path/to/repo.git/
>
> These two syntaxes are mostly equivalent, except **the former implies --local option.**

and

> -l, --local
>
> When the repository to clone from is on a local machine, this flag bypasses the normal "Git aware" transport mechanism and clones the repository by making a copy of HEAD and everything under objects and refs directories. The files under .git/objects/ directory **are hardlinked to save space when possible**.

So a shallow copy with `file:///path/to/repo.git/` syntax should consume more disk space than a full copy with `/path/to/repo.git/` syntax because the former has real copies of objects instead of hard links.

(And I believe that hard-linking is the reason why `--depth` get ignored when `--local` is set.)

**2. It doesn't save time either.**

Still, Git 2.24.1 manual:

> -l, --local
>
> When the repository to clone from is on a local machine, this flag **bypasses the normal "Git aware" transport mechanism** and clones the repository by making a copy of HEAD and everything under objects and refs directories. The files under .git/objects/ directory are hardlinked to save space when possible.

"Git aware" transport mechanism is time-consuming even when the URI is `file://...` because it includes object compressing:

```
$ time git clone --depth 1 --local --shallow-submodules file://$(pwd)/../linux
Cloning into 'linux'...
warning: --local is ignored
remote: Enumerating objects: 65607, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (65607/65607), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (61137/61137), done.
remote: Total 65607 (delta 4886), reused 39965 (delta 3556)
Receiving objects: 100% (65607/65607), 176.65 MiB | 10.81 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4886/4886), done.
Updating files: 100% (61793/61793), done.
git clone --depth 1 --local --shallow-submodules  73.55s user 4.97s system 245% cpu 31.976 total
```

(I don't know why the receiving speed is 10.81 MiB/s on my NVMe SSD)

And cloning with `--local` flag is much quicker:

```
$ time git clone ../linux
Cloning into 'linux'...
done.
Updating files: 100% (61793/61793), done.
git clone ../linux  4.16s user 1.71s system 100% cpu 5.857 total
```

Comment: Thank you for you clear explanation. However, I can't agree with you that it doesn't save space and isn't faster. It DOES save space, and, most importantly, DOES make things faster (well, just normal), in some circumstances. In my case, it is working on the mounted NFS share, and since it doesn't hard-link (thinks different machines maybe), and works so slow with many small files, it is a real problem. So, before judging "you are all wrong", think about use-cases you just didn't know about. But thanks.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. --local is also implied when copying between different drives. It seems fairly odd to overrule the user's explicit request based on the wrong condition.

Answer (score 2):

> But how to use relative paths with that?

This is not supported; `file://` expects only absolute paths.  There are e.g. [RFC1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.10) and [RFC8089](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8089#section-2) which describe this kind of URIs.

> A file URL takes the form:
>
> ```
>    file://<host>/<path>
> ```
>
> where  is the fully qualified domain name of the system on
> which the  is accessible, and  is a hierarchical
> directory path of the form //.../.

When you write `file://mymodule`, the `mymodule` can be interpreted as a hostname.

Answer (score -3):

You should try without the `file://` prefix:

```
git clone --depth 1 ./mymodule mymodule2
```

Comment: That's a great way to get the warning/error/bug described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40383230/1180930.